# How can I generate this reference style?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

> Hsiang, Solomon M., and Daiju Narita. 2012. Adaptation to cyclone
>   risk: Evidence from the global cross-section. Climate Change Economics
>   3 (2): 1-28.

The closest I have gotten is using `natbib` package and `authordate1`, but I get a "&" instead of "and" separating the two authors.

Does anyone know how to fix it? Is there any other approach?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407), showing us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Instead of looking far and wide for an already-existing bib style which may (or may not) satisfy one's exact formatting needs, it's much more efficient to run the `makebst` utility, which is part of the [custom-bib](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/) package. This utility (type `latex makebst` at a commmand prompt) presents a set of menu-driven questions with multiple-choice answers, and its output is a custom bst (bibliography style) file. The questions and possible choices are pretty much self-explanatory. When in doubt, choose the default answer.

Answer (score 1):

To change the `&` in the `authordate1` style into a `and`, search for [the file `authordate1.bst`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/authordate/authordate1.bst) and save it under a new name, for example `myauthordate.bst`, in the directory of your document.

In this file you have to search for

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
```

The code in this function is responsible for formatting the names, so if you replace

```
                { ", \& " * t * }                           %  Butcher, pages
```

by

```
                { ", and " * t * }                           %  Butcher, pages
```

you get a `and` instead of a `&`.

Of course you have to use `\bibliographystyle{myauthordate}` to actually use the customized style.

On the other hand  you should mind Micos comment: If can be much easier to create a new bibliography style with  the `makebst` utility (run `latex makebst` on the command line and follow the assistant) than finding and patching an existing one.